# JavaFX: add rows at the beginning of the TableView

Tags: java, javafx

I have a `TableView` with thousands of rows. Now I want to add rows at the beginng of the current table but not at the end. `TableView` keeps its items in [`ObservableList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html) . The only solution I see is to create new list (with new and old elements), clear current table and add new list to table. However, I need to do this operation constantly and from performance view it will be a nightmare. Are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ObservableList` extends `List` and therefore allows you to use any methods `List` declares, like [`List.add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-int-E-) and [`List.addAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html?is-external=true#addAll-int-java.util.Collection-):

```
TableView<MyItem> tableView = ...
List<MyItem> itemsToPrepend = ...
MyItem itemToPrepend = ...

tableView.getItems().addAll(0, itemsToPrepend);
tableView.getItems().add(0, itemToPrepend);
```

Answer (score 2):

The ObservableList is an Interface that extends of List interface:
[ObservableList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html) && [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

In List Interface have the method `add(index, element)` try to use `myObservableList.add(0, item)`;